# traversing up to change CSS in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok, real simple but its not working for me.  I want to change a class from hide to show traversing up the DOM from a specific link.  I thought I could do this with the parents() function but this is not working as expected.

```
<ul>
    <li class="lnav_parent ">
        <a class="137 bold" href="#">Top Parent</a>
        <div id="lnav_137" class="child hide">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="152" href="#">Some Parent</a>
                    <div id="lnav_152" class="child hide">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="755" href="#">Click Here</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
$('.755').parents('.child').addClass("show");
```

Basically any ancestor parent parent parent .child classes should add the class show or am I not explaining it well?

Comment: Looks like it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ScqY8/

Comment: How do you click something that's hidden ?

Comment: The element changes class when the page loads.  I got it to work, I just wanted to be sure that parents() was the best method for this and it was... Appreciate your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS class names aren't allowed to start with a number. That's most likely your issue.

Comment: Strictly-speaking, they *are* (certainly so far as HTML5 is concerned), but in CSS a number character, that's the *first* character, has to be escaped.

Comment: Yes I am using HTML5 and the numbers are strictly for jQuery not any CSS reasoning. I got it to work. See my answered question.

Answer (score 0):

So once I cleared my FireFox cache it worked.  I thought I was going crazy.  All the stars were aligned but there was no body home if that makes any sense.  Thanks for the quick replies. You all are very good and I appreciate it very much!!!